# Running Node from hostgator's vps

Tags: node.js, vps

Hi I'm new on setting up a VPS and I was wondering how to run nodejs on the server because I used ssh and run the node and it runs without a problem but as soon as I close the terminal and refreshed the page it was disconnected.. so I was wondering if there is a way on how to run node automatically let say similar to cronjob or something? I found this [Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742559/how-to-install-a-node-js-server-at-chat-mydomain-com-on-a-hostgator-vps-hosting) but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. Can someone enlighten me on this issue or give me some tips on how to do it..

Answer (score 1):

You want to run NodeJS as as service. This has already been addressed at StackOverflow:
[Node.js as a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service)