# How to set up node.js and socket.io based application on Hostgator VPS

Tags: node.js

I have VPS plan in Hostgator I have one chat application based on socket.io and node.js .I want to know how to set up this application to work on Hostgator.And how to make it to listen to port other than port 80 as it's already being used in running apache based application.

Comment: take a look at dokku: http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/ It's a heroku like deployment system which does a lot of the heavy lifting. Ideal for your own VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question is quite long to answer. First you might need to run you app as a service as answered here: [Running Node from hostgator's vps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173147/running-node-from-hostgators-vps)

And since port 80 is blocked you'll need to open a new port which is described here: [how to install a node.js server at chat.mydomain.com on a hostgator vps hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742559/how-to-install-a-node-js-server-at-chat-mydomain-com-on-a-hostgator-vps-hosting)

Then if you don't want your chat application to be accessed solely from a port you can install nginx to access it through a subdomain. You should start by reading here though: http://forums.hostgator.com/adding-nginx-vps-t93880.html

I asked a very similar question 3 years ago which you can read here: [hostgator vps level 1 & node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038387/hostgator-vps-level-1-node-js) 
This lead me to leave hostgator and move to digitalocean for all my node.js apps. Its a bliss and very quick to get all that you asked for up and running!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting DigitalOcean it's really quick to get started with. :)

Comment: Nice, I'm glad you like it! :)